# Very simple Javascript. What is this: "options = options || {};"?

Tags: javascript, variables, comparison

As stated in the title of my question,
I recently stumbled upon this variable declaration:

**options = options || {};**

So, as far as I understand - I am a beginner on lowest level - we have the global var options, which is assigned as...now I am lost...options or empty?

I know, this is probably an easy question, but I still don't seem to find a suitable answer.
All help is very appreciated.

With regards,
Julius

Comment: I can receive info for documentation where you find this condition (if) or code please...

Comment: The source can be found in line 26 of this document: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/03/custom-facebook-wall-jquery-graph/js/script.js

Comment: This statement (OR)s the empty object with variable itself. I think it ensures that `option` does not remain undefined after current statement (if it was undefined) or retain object's value.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, it is a duplicate! I understand it means, if options is not set, use {}. But what is {}? Empty array?

Comment: It's merely one way of creating a new empty object.

Comment: A general point to whoever is doing it: if you disagree with an answer please state why. All but one of the answers has been downvoted with no reason given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically means "if there is no options object currently defined, then create an empty object to populate the variable options".

So:

```
if(!options){

    options = {}

}else{ 

    options = options 

}
```

In response to your comment:

A `{}` is an empty object. It's akin to `new Object()`.

Comment: such unnecessary downvoting going on here... we don't need to split hairs over the semantics of `defined/undefined` - it's a pretty straight-forward explanation.

Comment: Thank you shennan, very simple and unarguably decent explanation

Answer (score 0):

It's a simplyfied version of:

```
if ( !options ) {
    options = {};
}
```

Another way of writing this is:

```
options || (options={});
```

It's simple create the object options if it's not allready set to anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's a way of initialising an object if it hasn't already been initialised.

If options exists, then it evaluates to:

```
    options = options
```

If options is null, then it treats it as 'false' and evaluates the second parameter, so becomes:

```
    options = {};
```

Comment: If whoever downvoted this would like to explain why, that'd be great ...

Answer (score 0):

It basically says "if `options` exists, then use it; otherwise, set `options` to an empty object."

Answer (score 0):

If the `options` object exists, define it as `options`. If it doesn't, create an empty object.